# System reboots when I disconnect Blackmagic eGPU from my Mac mini

Tags: macos, mac-mini, graphics, reboot

When I shut down the Blackmagic eGPU using the icon in the Menu bar:

[image: Diconnect AMD Radeon Pro 580]

Or if I manually unplug it, the system wants to reboot. All the applications ask "Do you want to close?" Then if I say no, at some point the reboot is cancelled, but half of my applications not asking for a confirmation close automatically. I am using a 2018 Mac mini running MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132)

How do I avoid this?

PS: I found a [related question without answer yet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/359503/67975).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS Mojave that you are currently running?

Comment: Have you visited Blackmagic Design's [support site](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/)?

Comment: Yes, sent an email. No answer so far.